# NodeJS csrf protection gives ForbiddenError invalid csrf token only on one POST request form

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, csrf, ejs

I have been unsuccessfully trying to find a solution on Google for the past several hours for the following issue:

I have csurf set up and working well. It works for POST requests related to signing up/in users. I am trying to create a form in the user profile, that updates the user's data, but when I hit submit, I get `ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token`.

On further testing, the csrt token is created on the profile page, but for some reason, it is invalid.

(I have only recently picked up programming, I'm willing to provide additional information if I have missed something.)

Tools used:

- Node.js v10.16.3
- Express v4.17.1
- ejs v2.7.1
- csurf v1.10.0
- Express session v1.16.2
- Passport v^0.4.0
- cookie-parser 1.4.4
- body-parser v1.19.0

My app.js

```
let express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
session = require("express-session"),
mongoose = require("mongoose"),
passport = require("passport"),
flash = require('connect-flash'),
validator = require('express-validator'),
LocalStrategy = require("passport-local"),
csrf = require('csurf'),
csrfProtection = csrf({ cookie: true }),
MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

let indexRoutes = require('./routes/index');
let userRoutes = require('./routes/user');
let User = require("./models/user");

// APP CONFIGURATION
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/azax", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, }).then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Something is wrong...");
});


require('./config/passport');

// View engine setup
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// Initial setup
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(validator());

// Session setup
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'somesecretforbytox',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(flash());

// Initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(csrf());

// CSRF
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var token = req.csrfToken();
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', token);
    res.locals.csrfToken = token;
    next();
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
});

// ======================
// Connect to route files
// ======================
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use(indexRoutes);

app.listen(3033, function () {
    console.log("Listening at port 3033...");
});
```

My passport.js:

```
let passport = require('passport');
let User = require('../models/user');
let LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
  req.checkBody('username', 'Invalid username').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty().isEmail();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty().isLength({ min: 4 });
  let errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    let messages = [];
    errors.forEach(function (error) {
      messages.push(error.msg);
    });
    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
  }
  User.findOne({ 'email': email }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Вече има акаунт с този имейл.' })
    }
    let username = req.body.username;
    let newUser = new User();
    newUser.username = username;
    newUser.email = email;
    newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
    newUser.country = 'България';
    newUser.save(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
      return done(null, newUser);
    });
  });
}));

passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
}, function (req, email, password, done) {
  // req.checkBody('username', 'Invalid username').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'Invalid email').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Invalid password').notEmpty();
  let errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    let messages = [];
    errors.forEach(function (error) {
      messages.push(error.msg);
    });
    return done(null, false, req.flash('error', messages));
  }
  User.findOne({ 'email': email }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Акаунтът не е намерен.' });
    }
    if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Грешна парола.' });
    }
    return done(null, user);
  });
}));
```

HTML...:

```
<form action="/user/profile" method="POST" class="form-validate form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit address</legend>
        <!-- email -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">
                <label id="jform_email1-lbl" for="jform_email" class="hasPopover required" title="" data-content="Enter new email address." data-original-title="Email Address">
                    Email<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="validate-email required" id="jform_email" value="<%= (typeof currentUser.email != 'undefined' ? currentUser.email : '') %>" size="30" autocomplete="email" required aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- name -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">
                <label id="jform_fname-lbl" for="jform_fname" class="hasPopover required" title="" data-content="Enter new name." data-original-title="Name">
                    Name<span class="star">&nbsp;*</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="jform_fname" value="<%= (typeof currentUser.firstName != 'undefined' ? currentUser.firstName : '') %>" class="required" size="30" required aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary validate">
            <span>Save</span>
        </button>
        <a class="btn" href="/" title="Cancel">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

user.js:

```
let express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    csrf = require('csurf'),
    csrfProtection = csrf(),
    passport = require('passport');

router.use(csrfProtection);
let User = require("../models/user");

// user profile
router.get("/profile", isLoggedIn, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
    res.render("user/profile", { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), currentUser: req.user });
});

router.post('/profile', (req, res) => {
    updateRecord(req, res);
    res.redirect('/profile');
});
// update user data
function updateRecord(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id }, (err, doc) => {
        doc.name = req.body.name;
        doc.save(function (err, doc) {
        });
    });
}
router.get("/profile/edit", isLoggedIn, csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
     res.render("user/edit", { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), currentUser: req.user });
});

// sign up form works with csrf

// signup form
router.get("/signup", csrfProtection, function (req, res) {
    let messages = req.flash('error');
    res.render("user/signup", { csrfToken: req.csrfToken(), messages: messages, hasErrors: messages.length > 0 });
});

// ... more routes

    module.exports = router;

// middleware
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/user/login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding the below hidden field to every form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
```

and sending the token  to every get request to the template page displaying the form.

```
{csrfToken: req.csrfToken()}
```

like

```
router.get('/user/login',function(req,res){
    res.render('pages/login', {csrfToken: req.csrfToken()});
})
```

this fixed the error in whole app.